# AlarmManager setting more than once?

Tags: android

I am using this code to set a Alarm everyday for 8 oclock the next day.
I am setting this alarm in an activity that can be opened based upon the user.

```
//Setting alarm to fire off NEW_GAME intent every 24 hours.
                String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                 Log.i("Test", "Current time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
                    Log.i("Test", "Calendar time: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis() );

                    int currentDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, currentDate+1);

                    Log.i("Test", "Calendar time with a day added: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis() );


                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(alarm);
                    Intent intent = new Intent("NEW_ITEM");
                    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
```

My only question is..Lets say at 10:00 o clock today am. i open the activity that alarm is set for tomorrow..Lets say i open the activity again at 12:00 am mid-night, will the alarm set earlier that day be overr written by the current alarm being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same request number (second parameter) while creating the PendingIntent object

```
 PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
```

then it will overwrite the current PendingIntent and hence will replace the current Alarm.

It will also depend on what you pass as the last parameter to it. Possible values given in the constants section [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).

Comment: So how i get around it overriding each other?

Comment: How do i set a unique value each time the activity is created?

Comment: You can generate a random number and assign it as the request number while creating the PendingIntent.

Comment: But the problem i see with this is..Say the user opens the activity more than once..the alarm will keep resetting with a random number.?

Comment: So you need only one alarm per day or something like that?

Comment: Yeah one alarm everyday at 8 oclock am